# How do I reset the transforms of an object to the original values?

Tags: transforms, world, origin

I think I accidently pressed something, and now I have the origin of the object away from the origin of the world, although, my other objects are working fine, and they "originate" from 0,0,0.
I tried to reset the origin (**Shift**+**Ctrl**+**Alt**+**C**, with all options in it).
I tried to move the object to 3d cursor(which is at 0,0,0, and then Origin to Geometry, Geometry to Origin), but still got those coordinates, where I messed up.
I also tried **Alt**+**G**, but it moves the object as well, which is not good in my case.

I also tried, to set the Pivot point to all the options in the list(Active, Median, 3D cursor etc).

And I also tried **Alt**+**,** to manipulate the center point, but with no luck.

[image: image_wrong_coords]

Above, you can see the object is at the 3d cursor(I have the padlocks clicked, but I unclicked them eventually) and at world 0,0,0, but the location is at an offset somewhere.

[image: image_ok_coords]

On this one, you can see, the location is 0,0,0, where it supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Shift C to set the 3D cursor in the center, then select the object and choose "set origin to 3D cursor". If still you have some offsets, check your object's "Delta transforms".

[image]

Comment: Thanks a plenty. It was the delta transform! Actually  I don't know how did I set them...

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> in 3d View panel will call the Apply menu:

[image]

By applying transforms you make them 0, but keep the object unchanged.

If you wanted to set the transforms to 0, you can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> for location, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for rotation and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for scale

Comment: I tried Alt+G before post, but did not work, and applying the location does the same thing. It translates the object to it's origin, but still to the "wrong" one. I want to set that origin to world 0,0,0.